# What is this markup in my browser... is it gltf?

Tags: three.js, makehuman

I'm working with makehuman.js.  I am trying to figure out how to export the model as it appears in the image.  Unfortunately I'm tied to at the latest Tree.js 8.3.  What is the markup showing up my console?  Is this GLTF or something else? Do these represent nodes in a tree? I am traversing the scene and printing results to the console.

```
                self.scene.traverse ( function (element) {
                    if (element.visible == true){
                    //var output = JSON.stringify( element, null, 2 );
                    console.log(element.id + " " + element.name + " " + element.node )
                    //console.log(output);
                    console.log(element); 
                 }
```

[image]

My GLTF Exporter:

```
            var gltfExporter = new THREE.GLTFExporter();

            var options = {
                trs: true,
                onlyVisible: true,
                truncateDrawRange: true,
                binary: false,
                forceIndices: true,
                forcePowerOfTwoTextures: true
            };

            gltfExporter.parse( self.scene, function ( result ) {
                 var output = JSON.stringify( result, null, 2 );
                 saveAs(new Blob( [output], {type : 'text/plain;charset=utf-8'}),'scene.gltf');                    
            }, options );
```

Comment: hey, funny library ;p From what I'm seeing, that 103 medievaldress Object with type 'object3D' is what you're after. It should be in scene.children. The GLTF Exporter expects an object3D. https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/exporters/GLTFExporter. The lower Object is also some kind of three.js object, because it has a property 'matrixAutoUpdate'.

Comment: Haha... yes I meant three.js 8.3.  I can't seem to use any later version without breaking things.  What I am trying to accomplish is much more complicated.  I am able to morph targets in this software and I am struggling with getting basically everything as seen in the window.  So far, I can get an Obj file with morphs but not the pose or any of the attached proxies.  My gltf output from the GLTF Exporter doesn't seem to have any of the makehuman objects... just other scene data like lights and the grid..